# GEE - Is there a way to divide an image to a set number of rows and columns, then export those smaller images?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, clip

I have a square over the area of interest. What I want to do is split the image that I've clipped from the square into 64 smaller squares, or maybe less like 16 smaller squares. After which I will export the 64/16 smaller squares instead of the larger original image. Code I use is below just in case it is possible I would know where to add the lines of code. If this isn't possible however, could someone tell me how I can achieve this outcome? Even manually in a GIS program.

```
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[120.60292703171366, 14.9078139009826],
          [120.60292703171366, 14.20599795613797],
          [121.29231912155741, 14.20599795613797],
          [121.29231912155741, 14.9078139009826]]], null, false);
    var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

var startDate = ee.Date('2021-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2021-10-01');

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT_TOA")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .select(['B7', 'B3', 'B1']);
  
var diff = endDate.difference(startDate, 'day');
var range = ee.List.sequence(0, diff.subtract(1)).map(function(day){
  return startDate.advance(day, 'day');
});

function perDayRename(date, newList){
  date = ee.Date(date);
  newList = ee.List(newList);
  
  var filtered = dataset.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'day'));
  
  var sysIndexInfo = ee.String('L8-T1-RT').cat(ee.String(date.get('year'))).cat(ee.String("_"))
  .cat(ee.String(date.get('month'))).cat(ee.String("_")).cat(ee.String(date.get('day')));

  //create mosaic
  var image = ee.Image(filtered.mosaic().clip(geometry))
  .set('Date', date).set('system:index', sysIndexInfo).set('system:time_start', date.millis());
  
  var output_img = ee.List(ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size(), newList.add(image), newList));
  return output_img;
}

//no cloud mask
var List = ee.List(range.iterate(perDayRename, ee.List([])));


// change to 'mosaicList' if without cloud mask
// change to 'mosaicListCloudless' if with cloud mask
var mosaicCol = ee.ImageCollection(List);
var visualization = {
  bands: ['B7', 'B3', 'B1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.4,
};
var imageList = mosaicCol.toList(mosaicCol.size());
for (var i = 0; i < mosaicCol.size().getInfo(); i++) {
  var image = ee.Image(imageList.get(i));
  Map.addLayer(image, visualization, 'Image ' + i);
}

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(mosaicCol, 'DataCollection', {
  scale: 30, 
  region: geometry, 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coveringGrid` to split a polygon into pieces.